# General hardening tips for a Apache Tomcat JSP application

Tags: java, security, jsp, jstl

I am currently developing a quite straightforward CRUD webapplication for a company. I am using the Apache Tomcat 6.0 and JSTL 1.2

The application is on the road to being finished and withstands constructive testing and basic mischief such as invalid input format in forms.

The security level doesn't have to be too high since it's only for internal use, but still I'd like to have the basics covered.

I am now trying to harden and or achieve failsafety/exceptionsafety and am looking for general hints and tipps where the usualy error sources lie.

What I already have thought of:

- SQL Injection ('fixed' using Prepared Statements)
- Fail gracefully on SQL-Exceptions
- Range checking on parameters such as pagenumbers

What are your recommendations to this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) guide on Tomcat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Securing_tomcat) is pretty thorough. Many excellent resources on that site.

Comment: This looks interesting. Seems I wasn't quite specific enough, the server and it's configuration is given (it's neither my job nor do I have the permission to change it). I am looking for ways to 'improve' my Servlet resp. JSP code. Since it's my first project of this kind, I probably didn't think of all obstacles when it comes to session management, user input sanitizing and so on

Comment: then again, i didn't look close enough at the site you pointed out... sorry

Comment: The quickest way to learn all of those things is probably to run an automated tool like [skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/) against your site to scan for vulnerabilities. This has the benefit of being both thorough in what it scans and unbiased.